# How do I display an MKMapView in ARKit?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to render an `MKMapView` on a plane in my ARKit app. I'm using SceneKit, but I'm open to using any renderer if it's easier.

Assume I have an `ARSCNView` called `sceneView`, and a `mapViewController` property that manages the `MKMapView` as its `view`. The frame of the map is set to `0, 0, 200, 200` in that view controller. Here is the `viewDidLoad` for the VC that manages my `ARSCNView`. Everything else is just an out of the box ARKit SceneKit app.

```
super.viewDidLoad()

let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.2, height: 0.2)
plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = mapViewController.view
        
let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        
let scene = SCNScene()
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
        
sceneView.scene = scene
```

I see a black plane when I start up my ARKit app, and I see three `Unsupported IOSurface format` messages.

I also occasionally see:

```
2020-07-01 01:53:34.473965-0400 MapDemo[5277:632686] [Animation] +[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:] being called from a background thread. Performing any operation from a background thread on UIView or a subclass is not supported and may result in unexpected and insidious behavior. trace=(
    0   UIKitCore                           0x00000001b75194d8 32D99ABD-E47B-38D8-BBD1-68AEA293A9A6 + 15938776
    1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102b5b18c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102b5cbd8 _dispatch_once_callout + 136
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00000001b751945c 32D99ABD-E47B-38D8-BBD1-68AEA293A9A6 + 15938652
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00000001b75195c8 32D99ABD-E47B-38D8-BBD1-68AEA293A9A6 + 15939016
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00000001b67c5514 32D99ABD-E47B-38D8-BBD1-68AEA293A9A6 + 1963284
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00000001b72a5ed8 32D99ABD-E47B-38D8-BBD1-68AEA293A9A6 + 13369048
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00000001b708d1bc 32D99ABD-E47B-38D8-BBD1-68AEA293A9A6 + 11170236
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00000001b72a3bb8 32D99ABD-E47B-38D8-BBD1-68AEA293A9A6 + 13360056
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00000001b708a6b8 32D99ABD-E47B-38D8-BBD1-68AEA293A9A6 + 11159224
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00000001b708b514 32D99ABD-E47B-38D8-BBD1-68AEA293A9A6 + 11162900
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00000001b708b26c 32D99ABD-E47B-38D8-BBD1-68AEA293A9A6 + 11162220
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001e9d2691c 00FB8022-069E-387B-8986-9BB204D26DA1 + 510236
    13  SceneKit                            0x00000001c7b50858 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 2345048
    14  SceneKit                            0x00000001c7b509d4 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 2345428
    15  SceneKit                            0x00000001c7b70fe8 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 2478056
    16  SceneKit                            0x00000001c79d8f90 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 806800
    17  SceneKit                            0x00000001c79a7a18 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 604696
    18  SceneKit                            0x00000001c79a7938 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 604472
    19  SceneKit                            0x00000001c79cb9ac 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 752044
    20  SceneKit                            0x00000001c79c8b78 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 740216
    21  SceneKit                            0x00000001c79c78d8 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 735448
    22  SceneKit                            0x00000001c79c67f4 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 731124
    23  SceneKit                            0x00000001c7af743c 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 1979452
    24  SceneKit                            0x00000001c7af7180 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 1978752
    25  SceneKit                            0x00000001c7afe63c 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 2008636
    26  SceneKit                            0x00000001c797f5a4 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 439716
    27  SceneKit                            0x00000001c7980edc 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 446172
    28  SceneKit                            0x00000001c7a807e8 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 1492968
    29  SceneKit                            0x00000001c7a81058 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 1495128
    30  SceneKit                            0x00000001c7a815e8 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 1496552
    31  SceneKit                            0x00000001c7a819b8 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 1497528
    32  SceneKit                            0x00000001c7b2023c 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 2146876
    33  ARKit                               0x00000001cf5f802c 687C8ABF-DCC3-39C9-8E21-CFA4150EEC6C + 1089580
    34  SceneKit                            0x00000001c79dd898 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 825496
    35  SceneKit                            0x00000001c7aea384 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 1926020
    36  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102b5b18c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    37  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102b6ac34 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 176
    38  SceneKit                            0x00000001c7aea308 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 1925896
    39  GPUToolsCore                        0x0000000102d6c114 -[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 172
    40  QuartzCore                          0x00000001b9a303f4 D29C2CDE-B325-3C54-9F2A-D626E512DE36 + 74740
    41  QuartzCore                          0x00000001b9b00290 D29C2CDE-B325-3C54-9F2A-D626E512DE36 + 926352
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b2e5d818 AF42303F-57B6-3C11-8F18-8E80ABF7D886 + 538648
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b2e881d8 AF42303F-57B6-3C11-8F18-8E80ABF7D886 + 713176
    44  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b2e8787c AF42303F-57B6-3C11-8F18-8E80ABF7D886 + 710780
    45  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b2e82374 AF42303F-57B6-3C11-8F18-8E80ABF7D886 + 689012
    46  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b2e818f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
    47  Foundation                          0x00000001b31cab18 19FAB59F-6527-3245-85BB-905FD4255CDE + 31512
    48  SceneKit                            0x00000001c79ddca0 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 826528
    49  SceneKit                            0x00000001c79ddf28 28F60AB7-97F2-368B-B5EE-81CB952B83E9 + 827176
    50  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b2c118fc _pthread_start + 168
    51  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b2c199d4 thread_start + 8
)
```

Is MapKit not supported in SceneKit?

Comment: No, the [SceneKit documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents) that you can't add the backing layer of a view as a material property. You would need to create a snapshot of the view to use it as a material. Do you need to interact with the view?

Comment: @jlsiewert Oh nice, thank you, I hadn’t seen that part of the documentation. I guess “already being displayed somewhere” still applies even though the view isn’t otherwise being displayed on screen? I do ideally want the user to be able to interact with the map. I guess I could proxy taps and pans to my `MKMapView` property, re-snapshot it, and display it, but that’s definitely more complex and potentially laggy. Do you have any other suggestions for how I might be able to get that to work?